# Multithreaded or asynchronous serial communication with several hardware units?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, pyserial

I have to interface a few identical hardware units that each communicate via RS232 serial communication on Windows using Python. Each hardware unit is connected via USB through a USB/Serial interface and exposed as a `COM` port on Windows. I want to be able to do the following:

- to control each hardware unit individually,
- to control all hardware units as a group,
- to send queries to individual units or all units and trigger appropriate actions based on the results,
- to listen to each individual unit for potential alarms sent through the serial communication and trigger appropriate action based on the alarm.

I believe the way to do this is to open one serial port with `pySerial` per individual hardware unit in a dedicated child thread capable of sending commands, queries, listening for alarms and either triggering actions at the hardware unit level or passing information to the parent thread that is controlling all children threads. Is this the right way to achieve the goals mentioned above?

I see that `pySerial` [supports some threading](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#module-serial.threaded). I see there also exist asynchronous implementation of serial communication, either in [pyserial-asyncio](https://pyserial-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or in [aioserial](https://github.com/changyuheng/aioserial.py) but I am not sure how that can help me in my use case. Can anybody explain the typical use cases for multithreading one or several serial communications or/and making it asynchronous?